# Can a traveler on a tourist visa reenter the US after 4 months?

Tags: visas, usa, colombian-citizens

I'm from Colombia and have a tourist visa. I went to the US in Oct 2014 and stayed till January 20, 2015. Can I get reenter the US on June 15, 2015?

Comment: Is your visa still valid?

Comment: Yes for 10 years

Comment: I assume your visa is a multiple-entry visa.  The border officer might suspect you of trying to establish yourself in the US.  Any evidence you can provide to show your planned return travel, ties to Colombia, etc., would be useful in such a case.  Don't volunteer it, though; just be prepared to show it if asked.

Comment: Did you depart the US by air?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your visa is valid on the day you go, you can (try to) enter the U.S.

There is never a guarantee any time a foreigner goes to the U.S. that they will be allowed entry or how long a duration of stay they will be given. An immigration officer could always, if he feels like, decide to deny entry or give a shorter duration of stay if he feels like the person has been to the U.S. too much recently, or other reasons; but your history of travel to the U.S. seems fairly modest, and there are visitors who go to the U.S. more densely with no problems.